# Create a map survey and download the result

Tags: leaflet, web-mapping, esri-leaflet

I have a shapefile of our state boundary. I want people to be able to drop a pin and add their names to the pin as an attribute. From there I would like to download all the pins as a shapefile and import it into GIS software.

Is anyone aware of a website or app that could accomplish this?

I do not need a basemap or imagery as I want the users to drop the pins on where they think the location is at without any context.

I'm not familiar with Leaflet, but could that possibly be a solution.

Comment: Are you looking for a pay or non-pay solution?

Comment: Do you have to use shapefile as the data format

Comment: Looking for a non-pay solution. Also, shapefile format is not required.

Comment: There are many options here, you might want to narrow down the question with a few details. Your going to need a database your web server can see. Since you're concerned with points it could be a MySQL, Postgresql, or others. Then you will need a service to post the data to the server, that could be PHP, NODE, JAVA, or something else. Then you need a service to send the data to the web page, in  JSON or GeoJSON format and display it in the map.  The short answer is Leaflet would work for this to display and capture the data.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into ArcGIS Survey123. It allows you to setup a survey where people can place a point as part of the survey, and you can easily export the data to CSV, Shapefile, Feature Service, etc.